# MPI: How to start three functions which will be executed in different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi

I have 3 function and 4 cores. I want execute each function in new thread using MPI and C++
I write this

```
int rank, size;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
size--;
if (rank == 0)
{
    Thread1();
}
else 
{
    if(rank == 1)
    {
        Thread2();
    }
    else
    {
        Thread3();
    }
}
MPI_Finalize();
```

But it execute just Thread1(). How i must change code?

Thanks!

Comment: What do the functions Thread1(), Thread2(), and Thread3() do?

Comment: Simple math operations and display results

Comment: MPI creates _multiple processes within their own separate address spaces_, not threads. What MPI version are you using? Microsoft MPI has issues with console redirection so you might not see output from ranks other than `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print to screen the current value of variable `size` (possibly  without decrementing it) and you will find `1`. That is: "there is `1` process running".

You are likely running your compiled code the wrong way. Consider to use **`mpirun`**  (or **`mpiexec`**, depending on your MPI implementation) to execute it, i.e.

```
 mpirun -np 4 ./MyCompiledCode
```

the `-np` parameter specifies the number of processes you will start (doing so, your  `MPI_Comm_size` will be 4 as you expect).

---

Currently, though, you are not using anything explicitly owing to C++.  You can consider some C++ binding of MPI such as [`Boost.MPI`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/mpi.html).

---

I worked a little bit on the [code](http://srcboard.com/yfa2e28) you provided. I changed it a little bit producing [this](http://srcboard.com/hjv7w18) **working** mpi code (I provided some needed correction in capital letters).

FYI:

- compilation (under gcc, mpich):

  ```
   $ mpicxx -c mpi1.cpp 
   $ mpicxx -o mpi1 mpi1.o
  ```
- execution

  ```
  $ mpirun -np 4 ./mpi1
  ```
- output

  ```
  size is 4
  size is 4
  size is 4
  2 function started.
  thread2
  3 function started.
  thread3
  3 function ended.
  2 function ended.
  size is 4
  1 function started.
  thread1
  1 function ended.
  ```

be aware that `stdout` is likely messed out.

Are you sure you are compiling your code the right way?

Comment: I haven't **mpirun** , but i have **mpiexec**. 

I run my app from cmd :

**mpiexec -np 4 ./MyApp.exe**


But on cmd i see just result of code before MPI function. And MPI functions aren't working.

Comment: @A.N.R.I..please consider my question. Btw why don't you consider shared memory multithreading (e.g. openMP)?

Comment: @A.N.R.I isn't `std::cout <<size;`  working? put it into `if (rank == 0)` section.  Does the code display anything? Usually there are issues using MPI and `stdout`.

Comment: @A.N.R.I, btw `mpi_init` should be put at the very top of the function. Secondly I would decouple the math from the multithreading. I.e. try with some expression of function `Thread`, outputting on different text files. In this way you would understand if you multithreading works correctly. Then put the math in.

Comment: I changed code to this http://srcboard.com/yfa2e28 and it's working but unparallel. Maybe i upload VS2010 project somewhere? It will be easy to see my project

Comment: @A.N.R.I consider the updated answer and the attached code. There a link with a working mpi code. Probably you have also to set your vs compiler (which I don't know). Btw, the code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that MPI provides no way to feed console input into many processes but only into process with rank `0`. Because of the first three lines in `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int oper;
    std::cout << "Enter Size:";
    std::cin >> oper;           // <------- The problem is right here

    Operations* operations = new Operations(oper);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int tid;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tid);
    switch(tid)
    {
```

all processes but rank `0` block waiting for console input which they cannot get. You should rewrite the beginning of your `main` function as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int oper;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int tid;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tid);

    if (tid == 0) {
       std::cout << "Enter Size:";
       std::cin >> oper;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&oper, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    Operations* operations = new Operations(oper);
    switch(tid)
    {
```

It works as follows: only rank `0` displays the prompt and then reads the console input into `oper`. Then a broadcast of the value of `oper` from rank `0` is performed so all other processes obtain the correct value, create the `Operations` object and then branch to the appropriate function.